# importing data from a pdf file into R

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, import, data-wrangling

Given [**page 4 of this PDF file**](https://tea.texas.gov/sites/default/files/Scale%20Score%20Distribution%20Graph%201_Grade%203%20to%208%20English-r2_tagged.pdf), I was wondering if there is a way (using any R library) to import the 2 columns named `SCALE SCORE` and `FREQ.` into R as a `.csv` or other R-friendly formats?

Comment: @Reza There is nothing harsh in me basically quoting the official SO documentation: [Please take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): "_Focus on questions about an **actual problem you have faced**. Include details about **what you have tried** and exactly what you are trying to do. [...] show your work!_". Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a package that can help extract text from pdfs. It's written from scratch in C++ and is fairly fast (usually a bit faster than pdftools). At the moment you still need to wrangle the text into a table - as you would in pdftools. In your case, it would work like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(PDFR)

df <- pdfpage("C:/users/Administrator/Documents/sales.pdf", 4)

df <- df[df$left > 440,] %>%
  group_by(top) %>%
  arrange(left, by_group = TRUE) %>%
  summarize(text = paste(text, collapse = ",")) %>%
  arrange(-top) %>%
  filter(seq(nrow(.)) > 4) %>%
  `[[`(2) %>%
  read.csv(text = ., header = FALSE, 
           col.names = c("freq", "cum_freq", "perc", "cum_perc"))
```

Which gives you:

```
#>     freq cum_freq perc cum_perc
#> 1    142      142 0.04     0.04
#> 2     15      157 0.00     0.04
#> 3     78      235 0.02     0.06
#> 4    269      504 0.07     0.13
#> 5    840     1344 0.21     0.34
#> 6   1690     3034 0.42     0.76
#> 7   3254     6288 0.81     1.57
#> 8   5413    11701 1.35     2.92
#> 9   7659    19360 1.91     4.83
#> 10  9696    29056 2.42     7.24
#> 11 11529    40585 2.87    10.12
#> 12 13145    53730 3.28    13.39
#> 13 13830    67560 3.45    16.84
#> 14 14844    82404 3.70    20.54
#> 15 15153    97557 3.78    24.32
#> 16 15120   112677 3.77    28.09
#> 17 15347   128024 3.83    31.92
#> 18 15525   143549 3.87    35.79
#> 19 15710   159259 3.92    39.70
#> 20 15596   174855 3.89    43.59
#> 21 15529   190384 3.87    47.46
#> 22 15451   205835 3.85    51.31
#> 23 15259   221094 3.80    55.12
#> 24 15028   236122 3.75    58.86
#> 25 15147   251269 3.78    62.64
#> 26 14683   265952 3.66    66.30
#> 27 14469   280421 3.61    69.91
#> 28 14229   294650 3.55    73.45
#> 29 13523   308173 3.37    76.82
#> 30 13246   321419 3.30    80.13
#> 31 12987   334406 3.24    83.36
#> 32 12264   346670 3.06    86.42
#> 33 11964   358634 2.98    89.40
#> 34 10841   369475 2.70    92.11
#> 35  9958   379433 2.48    94.59
#> 36  8529   387962 2.13    96.72
#> 37  6729   394691 1.68    98.39
#> 38  4437   399128 1.11    99.50
#> 39  2010   401138 0.50   100.00
```

Although this may seem a bit involved, it is great for pdfs like yours where the tables are the same on each page. If you ran the above code inside an `lapply` loop it could get multiple pages at a time far more quickly than cutting and pasting would.

To install you need devtools:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("AllanCameron/PDFR")
```

---

**Edit**

If there are installation problems, here is the equivalent in pdftools:

```r
install.packages(pdftools)

df <- pdftools::pdf_data("https://tea.texas.gov/sites/default/files/Scale%20Score%20Distribution%20Graph%201_Grade%203%20to%208%20English-r2_tagged.pdf")[[4]] 
df <- df[df$x > 440,] %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  arrange(x, by_group = TRUE) %>%
  summarize(text = paste(text, collapse = ",")) %>%
  arrange(y) %>%
  `[[`(2) %>%
  `[`(3:41) %>%
  read.csv(text = ., header = FALSE, 
           col.names = c("freq", "cum_freq", "perc", "cum_perc"))
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your package. I had been trying `tabulizer`, but bleh, `rJava`.

Comment: @IanCampbell thanks - it's a work in progress. It's good at extracting text and grouping into words and paragraphs. I haven't figured out a consistent way of getting it to reconstruct tables though. Please consider forking it and having a look.

Comment: Thanks, I have encountered many issues even trying to install your package.

Comment: @morouzian see my update for an alternative which is on CRAN and easier to install

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to do this one time is to select the data columns (but not the column headings). On page 4 of your pdf that is from 1038 in the upper left to 100.00 in the bottom right. Copy that selection to the clipboard:

```
dta <- read.table(pipe("pbpaste"))  # For Mac Os
# For Windows use dta <- read.table("clipboard")
dta <- dta[, 1:2]  # Discard the last three columns
colnames(dta) <- c("ScaleScore", "Freq")
head(dta)
#   ScaleScore Freq
# 1       1038  142
# 2       1171   15
# 3       1250   78
# 4       1299  269
# 5       1335  840
# 6       1364 1690
```

If you want to do this repeatedly, you will have to install package `pdftools`.

Comment: Try pasting into a text file using the R script editor or Notepad to make sure you have the data in the clipboard. If not, try to copy again.

Comment: Sure, but when I copy that content and paste onto a Notepad file, `read.table("clipboard")` gives me one column with everything meshed together?

Comment: You can wrap the single vector with `x <- data.frame(matrix(unname(unlist(dta)), length(dta)/5, 5, byrow=TRUE)[, 1:2])`. Then x will be your first two columns.